# Nativescript data-binding function calls not working

Tags: typescript, data-binding, nativescript, radlistview

In reference to this link https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#supported-expressions

```
function calls  myFunc(var1, var2, ..., varN)   Where myFunc is a function available in binding context (used as context for expression) or within application level resources. The value of the var1 and varN will be used as parameter(s).
```

Im using a RadList where for each item i have a Label where i need to show a composed string checking complex logics based on item params.

Can anyone give typescript example how we can use function calls. I tried many ways but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you share a [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org) with what you tried? That will make it easier to provide directions.

Comment: Playground sample: @anthares
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=qqFYFZ&v=3

Comment: @anthares Have you got time to check playground?

Comment: yeah, take a look at my response.

Comment: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Culita suggested - using $parent should work, but it doesn't. This seems like a bug to me, make sure to open a new issue about it in the [respective GitHub repository](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript).

As a workaround, you can create the function in the type you are using to bind the template to. In this case - it works as expected:

```
class Location {
    constructor(city: string, country: string, imageSrc: string) {
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.imageSrc = imageSrc;
    }

    city: string;
    country: string;
    imageSrc: string;

    getLabel(args): string {
        return "a" !== args ? "My label" + args : "Your Label ? " + args;
    }
}
```

Take a look at the [modified Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=qqFYFZ&v=5).

Comment: Thanks @anthares for the workaround.
I opened an issue for this https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7865

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and then you are free to use it by binding the property of the element to it.

```
getLabel(args): string {
    return "a" !== args ? "My label" + args: "Your Label ? " + args;
}


<Label text="{{ getLabel('dynamic') }}" class="lbl" textWrap="true" />
```

Comment: It didnt work. Logs error 
 CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/js-libs/polymer-expressions/polymer-expressions.js:186:24: Cannot find function or filter: getLabel

Comment: can you share a Playground Sample?

Comment: Got the issue. This worked when it is in simple page. Im having a RadListView and for an item title i tried this. There it didnt work. Any clue? @Culita

Comment: Playground sample:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=qqFYFZ&v=3

Comment: According to the NS documentation, the template doesn't have the same binding context. You need to use the special keyword $parent or $parents to be able to access the parent binding context.

https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-a-parent-binding-context

Comment: I tried this. Im able to show the binding param of that page using $parents['RadListView'].title. but Im not able to use a function from that view model class. It shows like [object object]